# Binomial & Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

**Problem:**

A hospital receives 70% of its flu vaccine from Company G and the remainder from company E. Each shipment contains a large vial of vaccine. From Company G, 10% of the vials are ineffective. From Company E, 80% are ineffective. A hospital tests n=10 randomly selected vials from one shipment from their effectiveness.

For the problem
: "Compute the probability that exactly two of these 10 vials are
ineffective."

I'm separating the case into three: 1 from G 1 from E + 2 from G + 2 from E. However, I'm having problems finding the probabilities.

**My question:**

i. "P(1 from G 1 from E)" can I just times P(pick1 from G) * P(pick1 from E)? ---> [(seven pick one) times 0.9^6 times 0.1] * [(three pick one) times 0.2^2 times 0.8]?

ii. Is "P(2 from G)"'s coefficient (7 pick 2) since the average possibility to have the vials from company G is 7 out of 10.

Comment: **Warning:** You need to consider the origin of all 10 vials.

Comment: Let $A$ be the probability that given 10 vials from company G, exactly $2$ of the 10 vials are ineffective.  Let $B$ be the probability that given 10 vials from company E, exactly $2$ of the 10 vials are ineffective.  Then the desired computation is $[(0.7 \times A) + (0.3 \times B)]$.  See also [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k} p^k q^{n-k}.$

Comment: See also, my comment following the answer of Graham Kemp.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You have not be told that exactly 7 of the 10 vials are from G, but rather that on average $70\%$ of all vials are.

---

You have ten vials, each of which is independently $70\%$ probable to be from $G$, else its from $E$ .

Those from G are $10\%$ probable to be ineffective, while those from E are $80\%$ probable .

So use the Law of Total Probability to find $p$, the probability that a particular vial is ineffective.

Express the probability that two among the ten vials are independent using $p$; then evaluate.

Comment: I am unsure whether your interpretation of the problem represents the problem composer's intent.  See my comment following the original posting.  I interpret that $70$% of the time, all $10$ vials come from G and the other $30$% of the time, all $10$ vials come from E.  Perhaps my interpretation is wrong.

Comment: Hmm... That is a possible interpretation.  But it does say "Each shipment contains one vial" and they have 10 vials.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem with my interpretation.  The problem with your interpretation is "A hospital tests n=10 randomly selected vials from one shipment from their effectiveness."  So, either interpretation has a flaw, which means that the problem is poorly written, regardless of which interpretation is accurate.  I opted for my interpretation because it seems more realistic and because it seemed to present an easier problem to solve.  Your interpretation results in a somewhat more complicated problem to solve.